# Typescript: cast strict primitive type to primitive

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I have a function that parse string to value, and returns `defaultValue` if fails. Problem is that this code returns too strict types for primitives (e.g. `false` instead of `boolean`). How can I fix it? Maybe I should use some cast for `defaultValue`? Thanks

```
export function safeParse<T>(text: string, defaultValue?: T): T | undefined {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(text);
  } catch {
    return defaultValue; // some cast here?
  }
}

const res1 = safeParse('128', 0); // typeof res1 is '0 | undefined'
const res2 = safeParse<number>('128', 0); // OK: typeof res2 is 'number | undefined'
const res3 = safeParse('128', 0 as number); // OK: typeof res3 is 'number | undefined'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will be useful

```
type StrictType<T> = T extends number
    ? number
    : T extends string
        ? string
        : T extends boolean
            ? boolean
            : T


export function safeParse<T>(text: string, defaultValue?: StrictType<T>): StrictType<T> | undefined {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(text);
  } catch {
    return defaultValue; // some cast here?
  }
}

const res1 = safeParse('128', 0); // typeof res1 is 'number | undefined'
const res2 = safeParse('true', false); // typeof res2 is 'boolean | undefined'
```